# Добавление строки в таблицу-посредник Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, java

Добрый день!
В БД реализована связь многие ко - многим между params,params_and values,launches: 
[image]

Мне необходимо вставить сущности в launches, params_and_values, для каждого значения из params. hibernate-код вставки данных:

```
        currSes=  HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    currSes.beginTransaction();
    Collection<ParamsEntity> pe = currSes.createCriteria(ParamsEntity.class).list();
    Hibernate.initialize(pe);
    currSes.getTransaction().commit();



    for (ParamsEntity paramsEntity : pe) {
        currSes=  HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        currSes.beginTransaction();
        le= (LaunchesEntity) currSes.load(LaunchesEntity.class, launchId);
        ParamsAndValuesEntity pve= new ParamsAndValuesEntity();
        pve.setLaunchesByLaunchId(le);
        pve.setParamsByParamsId(paramsEntity);
        pve.setParamValue("meow");
        currSes.save(pve);
        currSes.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

Выскакивает исключение:

```
MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a   foreign key constraint fails
```

Почему это не работает?=(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблемы с внешними ключами.

Попробовать сделать так:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1
```

Вам нужно разобраться в ключах и порядке записи.

Comment: ну порядок записи вроде бы верный : Я сначала в таблицу сохраняю таблицы между которыми связь многие-ко-многим, а только потом их айди пишу в таблицу-посредник и сохраняю ее

Comment: ошибка заключается в том, что функция *save* не возращает сгенерированный id:

              LaunchesEntity le= new LaunchesEntity();
        le.setDateStart(currDate);
        le.setDateEnd("");
        le.setLaunchName("my_launch");
        le.setStatus("instance");
        le.setRequestText("my_req_text");
        Integer launchId = (Integer) currSes.save(le);
        currSes.getTransaction().commit();


*launchId* равен 0 , при этом таблица норм создается. Почему id не присваивается? Подозреваю, что *id* генерируется при коммите, как это исправить

Comment: Посмотрите пример работы с Hibernate – Many-To-Many Example (Annotation) http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

В этом примере очень хорошо показано как работать со связями многие ко многим.

Comment: Проблема решена. Id записи присваивается только когда она персистентна. Тоесть мне надо закомитить изменения и только потом брать id